# And condition doesn't seem to work in validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to create a validation rule to fire if owner of a record is active then its owner cannot be changed. But doesn't seem to work?

```
AND(      
  Owner:User.IsActive = true,    
  ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
)
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/373030/edit) your question to add the important information that you included in comments on @SaiPraveenKakkirala 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it doesn't work because your Validation Rule will be triggered when: **The owner changed and the new owner is active**

What you would like to achieve would be:

```
AND(
  PRIORVALUE(Owner:User.IsActive) = true,    
  ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
)
```

Unfortunately you cannot use `PRIORVALUE` with such parameter. There is a workaround for this, you simply have to create a formula field `OwnerIsActive__c` with formula `Owner:User.IsActive` and then use it in your Validation Rule like that:

```
AND(
  PRIORVALUE(OwnerIsActive__c) = true,    
  ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
)
```

P.S : Using `Owner:User.IsActive` is valid for all objects that accept queue as owner, otherwise use `Owner.IsActive`.

Comment: Correct. This is the way to go as also was suggested by Sai. Thanks for the details Bartheleway.

Answer (score -1):

You had a small error in the validation rule.Can you use the below validation rule

```
AND( ischanged(OwnerId),Owner.IsActive = true )
```

And on lead object the below validation rule is working as expected.

We cannot add PRIORVALUE to the related object field like to the User object active field. You may have to use the trigger logic to fire the validation or create a formula field to get the active field on user to lead and use the PRIORVALUE on that field

Comment: Error: Specify an object type for the Owner field.

Comment: Can i know on which object you are trying this rule. I tried on Opportunity and it worked with out any error .

Comment: Validation rule is on Lead object.

Comment: If that is on lead object The below validation rule is working as expected. `AND( ischanged(OwnerId),Owner:User.IsActive=true)`. I tried to update the owner of the lead and the present owner is already active and validation rule got fired

Comment: Yes, its firing but the problem is its also firing when the leads record owner is inactive as well. So its firing for both conditions, when the record owner is active and also when its inactive. It should not fire when the record owner is inactive.

Comment: This is checking only the present value. So you may have to use the prior value function but it is not possible to use prior value function to the related object values. So you may have to use some trigger logic or create a formula field to get that value. Added the same to the answer

Comment: @Col : In two comments you stated, "Validation rule is on Lead object," and, "Yes, its firing but the problem is its also firing when the leads record owner is inactive as well." *That is information which should have been included in your original question.* Posters need to remember that we are neither in your minds nor in your orgs, so you have to give us all of the information.

Comment: Yes Sai, a new formula field has to be created. Will take that approach. And Moonpie, noted your point.